# CSS and HTML- Dropdown Menu Pushing Down Content-- Position: relative and absolute not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to work with my wordpress HTML to style the nav menu I've created. I've instituted the `:hover` thing, and the dropdown is in place. It pushes down the content in my website when hovered over. I tried the `z-index` fix as well as the `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`. If I use the relative and absolute positions fix, the dropdowns do this odd thing where the background color disappears and all my submenu `ul`s are stacked overlapping each other. Any advice as to why?

Here's the JSfiddle I've uploaded everything to. https://jsfiddle.net/alexisrambles/j0935on2/10/

Here's the CSS I've got so far.

```css
#menu-apl {

  background-color: #63afe6;
  width: 100%;

}

li.dropdown {

  list-style: none;
  background-color: #63afe6;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

li a {

  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;

}


//////////////



.dropdown {

  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #63afe6;

}

.dropdown-item {

  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;


}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-item {

  display: block;

}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
  <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-b46d8b5 elementor-widget elementor-widget-wp-widget-nav_menu" data-id="b46d8b5" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="wp-widget-nav_menu.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <div class="menu-apl-container">
        <ul id="menu-apl" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-806" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-806">
            <a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/home/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-790" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page <menu-item-has->                  </menu-item-has->children menu-item-790">
            <a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/about/">About</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-793" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type 
          <menu-item-object->    </menu-item-object->page menu-item-793">
                <a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/employment/">Employment</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-791" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type <menu-item-object->  </menu-item-object->page menu-item-791">
                <a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/library-board/">Library Board</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-792" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-792">
                <a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/friends-of-the-library/">Friends of the Library</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-795" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-795"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/services/">Services</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li id="menu-item-804" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-804"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/request-a-book/">Request a Book</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-803" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-803"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-802" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-802"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/meeting-room-policy/">Meeting Room Policy</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-801" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-801"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/interlibrary-loan/">Interlibrary Loan</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-800" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-800"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/fines-and-fees/">Fines and Fees</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-799" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-799"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/ebook-catalog/">Ebook Catalog</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-798" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-798"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/databases/">Databases</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-797" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-797"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/card-catalog/">Card Catalog</a></li>
              <li id="menu-item-796" class="dropdown-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-796"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/library-policies/">Library Policies</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-794" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-794"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/locations/">Locations</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code to remove all the stuff from the HTML that isn't relevant to this question, to avoid distractions. Then I edited the CSS.

Two things:

1. You need to remove all those slashes in the CSS because they are making it invalid, which causes the next block of styles after them to not get applied.
2. To get the relative/absolute positioning combo to work correctly, you need to make sure you are positioning the right things.

Before, you were focusing on the menu items themselves – that's what you were switching from `display: none` to `display: block`, and I suspect that's what you were trying to absolutely position as well. If you absolutely position all the menu items and give them all styles of, say, `top: 0; left: 0`, they will all sit on top of each other. Instead, try positioning the list (i.e., `ul.sub-menu`) relative to its parent list item (i.e., `li.dropdown`).

From there, you can use the immediate sibling selector `+` to change the styling on hover. So when you hover a link, the sub menu immediately after it appears.

Last thing to do to make sure you can actually see this in action is to give the dropdown a background color, so I've done that below as well.

```css
#menu-apl {
  background-color: #63afe6;
  width: 100%;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #63afe6;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #63afe6;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-item {
  width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #63afe6;
}
.dropdown a:hover + .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/home/">Home</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/about/">About</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/employment/">Employment</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/library-board/">Library Board</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/friends-of-the-library/">Friends of the Library</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/services/">Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/request-a-book/">Request a Book</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/meeting-room-policy/">Meeting Room Policy</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/interlibrary-loan/">Interlibrary Loan</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/fines-and-fees/">Fines and Fees</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/ebook-catalog/">Ebook Catalog</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/databases/">Databases</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/card-catalog/">Card Catalog</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/library-policies/">Library Policies</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="https://www.alexisrichard.com/locations/">Locations</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here it is on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9zsp7t1/.

Comment: Oh jeez. Thank you so much. I was getting really frustrated and I knew it was probably something fairly innocuous.

Thank you also for pointing out that the :hover should be on .dropdown a, not just .dropdown. Lesson learned--if you're frustrated you're probably missing something fairly obvious lol.

Oh also, that immediate sibling selector is really interesting. Thanks for that too--now I can look into that as well.

Comment: @AlexisRichard happy to help! If your problem is solved, please consider accepting and upvoting this answer.